# Usuario pide permisos a otro [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un blog en `Wordpress` y quiero que cuando un usuario haga un post, si quiere modificarlo o eliminarlo debería pedir permiso a algún administrador y este concederselo, o no.

La cosa es que estoy buscando en internet y no consigo encontrar nada ni siquiera parecido.

Por eso he acudido a esta web, para ver si alguien puede orientarme en el tema, ya sea con algún tipo de plugin que conozca, o haciendo lo pertinente vía código.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No soy experto, pero creo que eso que dices no se puede hacer automaticamente

Comment: Creo que el [rol Colaborador](https://en.support.wordpress.com/user-roles/) o Contributor, de Wordpress, haría eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si eso es lo que quieres de verdad, osea tener control sobre las personas que te votan, también tienes que tener control sobre las que lo ven, deberías de hacer el wordpress privado.

Si lo tienes público, que todos los pueden ver, creo que no vas a poder tener control sobre los que te votan.

Por último podrías poner el plugin de editor de roles y especificar lo que puede hacer cada rol.

Creo que lo que de verdad necesitas, si he entendido bien es

**[User Role Editor](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)**

Comment: A ver, es que creo que no he formulado bien la pregunta. Mi sitio web es uno donde hay usuarios que se registran y realizan tutoriales sobre distintas categorías. Estos usuarios cuando realizan un tutorial pasa a estado de "Esperando revisión" hasta que un administrador lo confirme. Y mi petición viene justo despues de esto. 

Una vez el tutorial está creado, si el usuario que lo ha creado quiere eliminarlo o modificarlo debería mandar una petición al administrador que corresponda, y este debe aceptarlo o no, y eso con los editores de roles habituales no es posible hacerlo (creo).

Comment: Con los editores de roles puedo o permitir que un usuario elimine o borre, o que no tenga esa capacidad, pero darsela o no dependiendo de si un administrador así lo desea es lo que me deja en jaque.

Comment: Y no es más fácil aún, ya que están registrados puedes crear varios roles diferentes dependiendo del estado en el que se encuentre, creo que teniendo diferentes usuarios con diferentes accesos y que vaya evolucionando según las cosas que pueda hacer. Por eso te comenté lo del uso de roles.

Comment: Vale, creo que he entendido la filosofía, voy a intentar hacerlo de esa manera. Muchas gracias por todo.